# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in JSON parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Please help me debug this code

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cnapi.iconnectgroup.com/api/UserProfile?id=1"]];
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urls encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        NSLog(@"JSon data = %@ and Error = %@", json, error);
    if(!error)
    {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSArray *myJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON data is :: %@", myJsonArray);

        for(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
        {
            //NSString *uids = jsonDictionary[@"UID"];
            NSString *address1 = jsonDictionary[@"Address1"];
            NSString *address2 = jsonDictionary[@"Address2"];
            NSString *city = jsonDictionary[@"City"];
            NSString *emailId = jsonDictionary[@"EmailID"];
            NSString *fname = jsonDictionary[@"FName"];
            NSString *fax = jsonDictionary[@"Fax"];
            NSString *lname = jsonDictionary[@"LName"];
            NSString *password = jsonDictionary[@"Password"];
            NSString *phone = jsonDictionary[@"Phone"];
            NSString *state = jsonDictionary[@"State"];
            NSString *uids = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"UID"];
            NSString *zip = jsonDictionary[@"Zip"];
            NSString *company = jsonDictionary[@"company"];
            NSString *department = jsonDictionary[@"department"];

            NSLog(@"Uid is = %@", uids);
            NSLog(@"First Name = %@", fname );
            NSLog(@"Last Name = %@", lname);
            NSLog(@"Company = %@", company);
            NSLog(@"Email Id = %@", emailId);
            NSLog(@"Password = %@", password);
            NSLog(@"Department = %@", department);
            NSLog(@"Address 1 = %@", address1);
            NSLog(@"Address 2 = %@", address2);
            NSLog(@"City = %@", city);
            NSLog(@"State = %@", state);
            NSLog(@"Zip = %@", zip);
            NSLog(@"Phone = %@", phone);
            NSLog(@"Fax = %@", fax);

        }
    }

  });
    [activity stopAnimating];
    self.activity.hidden = YES;
}
```

Image will give you where the error is. I get this error after clicking stepover to debug. I also tried

```
NSString *address1 = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Address1"];
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see on the console when you log the contents of myJsonArray?

Comment: Are you sure jsonDictionary is an NSDictionary, I think it is a string

Comment: show your myJsonArray

Comment: Show your JSON. You seem to be confused about data types.

Comment: @Deepak Are you sure its JSON? The URL in your code(`http://cnapi.iconnectgroup.com/api/UserProfile?id=1`) returns an XML response!

Comment: @Amar even though in browser it gives xml, in iOS it gives json. I would not have got these { } in log JSON : {
    Address1 = "<null>";
    Address2 = "<null>";
    City = "<null>";
    EmailID = "test@yahoo.com";
    FName = test;
    Fax = "";
    LName = User;
    Password = test;
    Phone = "<null>";
    State = "<null>";
    UID = 1;
    Zip = "<null>";
    company = IConnect;
    department = "<null>";
    flag = "<null>";
    message = "<null>";
}

Comment: @DeepakThakur Then its okay, that's why I asked if you are sure? You should add the JSON in the question.

Comment: This isn't JSON (it's not key-value pairs separated by ":"): { Address1 = "<null>"; Address2 = "<null>"; City = "<null>"; EmailID = "test@yahoo.com"; FName = test; Fax = ""; LName = User; Password = test; Phone = "<null>"; State = "<null>"; UID = 1; Zip = "<null>"; company = IConnect; department = "<null>"; flag = "<null>"; message = "<null>"; }. What is this output from?

Comment: It is JSON - but it's just one long NSString:)

Comment: I think the problem begins already from *myJsonArray, for there is no indication of array value to begin with. Try to replace your *myJsonArray with a NSDictionary and see.

Comment: @Unheilig : i still get the same error as I have uploaded in the screenshot after replacing NSArray with NSDictionary

Comment: NSLog myJsonArray and copy/paste the output of that plus your entire original JSON string into your question.  *Do not* put images into your question -- copy in the text and format it as "code" (using the `{}` button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output of url, it shows it's not array but a dictionary. You are trying to convert to array here.

```
NSArray *myJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

instead use this

```
 NSDictionary *myJsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

then remove that for loop no need of it. and replace your variable jsonDictionary with myJsonDictionary so to retrieve values.

```
// for(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
```

**Run now it will be fine. Worked for me fine**

If the output was array of Dictionaries it would have been looked like this with square brackets around.

```
For Ex: [{"id": "1", "name":"Aaa"}, {"id": "2", "name":"Bbb"}]
```

> If you are not sure of nature of response from url you can check for
>   the type. For ex:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData   options:0 error:nil];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array!");

    NSArray *myJsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
   // Handle Array of Dictionary

for(NSDictionary *jsonDictionary in myJsonArray)
    {
        NSString *address1 = jsonDictionary[@"Address1"];
       //and so on
    }
}
else {
NSLog(@"It's Dictionary");
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
NSLog(@"jsonDictionary - %@",jsonDictionary);
//Handle NSDictionary
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jsonDictonary is a NSString not as you expect NSDictonary.

Double check your JSON and maybe before calling that function check if it's NSDictonary.

Comment: if I replace NSDicationary in for lop with NSString, I get multiple compile time error stating "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSString *' "

Comment: @DeepakThakur -- Actually *look* at your JSON and *understand* what it means, then shape the code to match.  Don't copy code from somewhere else and just try to hack it until it works.  JSON is *very simple* if you but try to understand it first.  See json.org.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use one of the semi-standard frameworks for parsing JSON into Core Data. There are some SO questions  about those.

In this case, your JSON has only one object which is not an array. 
In general, your app shouldn't abort if server sent something unexpected, so it's better to use a parser which will loudly complain about malformed JSON than with it from scratch.